# install weblogic on console mode without xming

Tags: oracle, installation, weblogic

I'm trying to install **weblogic** server on **Centos 7** with following instruction of oracle about console mode. Everything will be fine till  weblogic  file 's extracting on my computer. I get this message about

> display enviroment variable  failed

I google it and found **xming** as solution. But is there any solution to install weblogic without xming.

Comment: Console mode is not available in last versions of weblogic server, you have to use the silent mode installation or the GUI.

Comment: Have you already attempted using option "-mode=console" with the WebLogic installation binary ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do a silent install as mentioned. You can find the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/OUIRF/silent.htm).

Basically, you need two files:

- A response file

Here, you will set some parameters like ORACLE_HOME, proxy information if needed and installation type, etc.

- An oraInst.loc file

In this file, you need to do the following(from documentation):

> Replace oui_inventory_directory with the full path to the directory where you want the installer to create the inventory directory. Then, replace oui_install_group with the name of the group whose members have write permissions to this directory.

After doing all of this, you can run the command as follows;

> java -jar distribution_name.jar -silent -responseFile file [-options] [()*]

I uploaded my own oraInst.loc and response files [here](https://idrive.innova.com.tr/index.php/s/oLJam5NhrMbygAQ) for demonstration. I strongly suggest you to read the documentation though. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks dude , with your solution  my problem is solved .